# Proof of a limit using the formal definition

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

I have been tasked to prove the following:

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{3x+2}{4x^2} = \infty$$

using the $(\epsilon,\delta)-$definition of a limit.

I know that we can say:

$$\lim_{x \to a}f(x) = \infty$$

If

$\forall K>0,\, \exists\delta > 0$ such that $|f(x)| > K$ when $|x-a| < \delta$.

I have tried approaching this problem as such:

Given $K >0,\,$ we must find a $\delta > 0,\,$ such that

$|f(x)| = |\frac{3x + 2}{4x^2}| > K$ when $|x-a| = |x| < \delta$.

So,

$|3x+2| > K|4x^2| \implies |3x+2| > 4Kx^2 \implies x^2 < \frac{|3x+2|}{4K}$.

Now to isolate $x,\,$ we choose $|x| < \frac{1}{3} \implies 1 < 3x+2 < 3$.

Therefore,

$x^2 < \frac{|3x+2|}{4K} < \frac{3}{4K} \implies |x| < \frac{3}{4K}$

which means we must satisfy both $|x| < \frac{3}{4K}$ and $|x| < \frac{1}{3}$.

Hence, we must choose $\delta = \min(\frac{1}{3},\frac{3}{4K})$.

Is this sufficient to prove this limit?

Comment: "$x^2 < \frac{|3x+2|}{4K} < \frac{3}{4K} \implies |x| < \frac{3}{4K}$"  How'd you go from $x^2$ to $|x|$?  $x^2 \ne |x|$ but $\frac 3{4K} = \frac 3{4K}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close.

$x^2 < \frac {3}{4K}$  and $3x + 2 < 3$ does not means $x^2 < \frac {|3x +2|}{4K}$.

But $x^2 < \frac {1}{4k}$ and $1 < 3x+2$ does mean that $x^2 < \frac {|3x +2|}{4K}$.

You want $x^2 \le \frac 1{4K} < \frac {|3x +2|}{4K}$

And then you want  the square root of $\frac 1{4K}$ and chose $\delta = \sqrt{\frac 1{4K}}$.

But in my opinion I really don't like this work backwards and find $\delta$ proofs.  I always suspect the student doesn't understand the concept and is trying to replicate rules they do not understand.

If one says and the beginning "Therefore it will be sufficient to prove such a delta exists, by finding a possible delta" would be acceptable.

But I believe all this business of finding the delta should be done on scratch paper *before* even beginning the proof.  Then once you figure the delta, you start the actual "final draft" of the proof:

.......

For any $K$ let $\delta = \min (\frac 13, \sqrt{\frac 1{4K}})$.

Then whenever $|x| < \delta$ then $1 < 3x +2 < 3$.  We also have $x^2< \frac 1{4K} < \frac {3x + 2}{4K}$.

So $K < \frac {3x+2}{x^2}$

So $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac {3x+2}{x^2} = \infty$.

......

P.S.

> I know that we can say:
>
> limx→af(x)=∞
>
> If
>
> ∀K>0,∃δ>0
> such that |f(x)|>K when |x−a|<δ.

Not, quite.  You actually simply want $f(x) > K$.  Not $|f(x)| > K$.

Comment: Very well explained, thank you! My lecturer only defined the proof with absolute values, so completing it in this way seems like a lot less hassle! Must we only want $|f(x)| > K$ when the limit tends to minus infinity then? Also, I must agree, the four line proof is much more concise!